# Show that $g(X)=\{f(x)|x\in X\},X\subseteq A$ is bijective.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $f:A\to B$ be bijective. Show that $g:P(A)\to P(B)$, defined as $$g(X)=\{f(x)|x\in X\},X\subseteq A$$ is also bijective.

Let's first try to show that $g$ is injective. So we need to show that if $g(X_1)=g(X_2)$, then $X_1=X_2$. $$g\left(X_1\right)=g\left(X_2\right)\land X_1\subseteq A\land X_2\subseteq A\\X_1,X_2\subseteq A\land \{f(x)|x\in X_1\}=\{f(x)|x\in X_2\}\\X_1,X_2\subseteq A\land\forall x\left(x\in\{f(x)|x\in X_1\}\iff x\in\{f(x)|x\in X_2\}\right)$$
I have basically used the fact that $A=B\iff \forall x(x\in A \iff x\in B)$, as we have $g(X_1)=g(X_2)$ and using the definition of $g$ gives what I wrote.
I don't know how to show from here that $X_1=X_2$ which is enough to say that $g$ is injective. Where am I supposed to use that $f$ is bijective?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a heads up that just writing a long string of logical symbols like this makes your attempt much harder to read. Try using more words instead

Comment: @Lorago, thank you! I tried to clarify what I did as detailed as I could.

Comment: Hint: $X=\{f^{-1}(y)\mid y\in f(X)\}.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first want to show $X_1 \subset X_2$. So, let $x_1 \in X_1$. Then $f(x_1) \in \{f(x) \mid x \in X_1\} = g(X_1)$. We know $g(X_1)=g(X_2)$. It then follows that
$$f(x_1) \in g(X_2) = \{f(x) \mid x \in X_2\}$$
That means that there exists a $x_2 \in X_2$ such that
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$
But since $f$ is a bijection we can look at the inverse of both sides giving us:
$$x_1=x_2$$
and since $x_2 \in X_2$ we have
$$ x_1 = x_2 \in X_2$$
So $x_1 \in X_2$ which shows that
$X_1 \subset X_2$. The other inclusion follows analogously.

Comment: Thank you! Do we really need that $f$ is surjective as well though?

Comment: @MathStudent In this proof we only need injectivity. However, that proof only gives the injectivity of $g$. But you also want to show the surjectivity of $g$ where we will need the surjectivity of $f$.

Comment: Yep, I reached to that conclusion as well. May you give me a hint for the surjectivity? We start with $Y\in P(B)$, right? And now how do we find a set $X\in P(A)$ s.t. $g(X)=Y$? That's the idea, right?

Comment: @MathStudent Yes exactly. As a hint look at the set $\{x \in A \mid f(x) \in Y\}$.

Comment: Ugh, sorry, but this hint isn't enough for me. Can you clarify it a bit more?

Comment: @MathStudent $$g(\{x\in A\,|\,f(x)\in Y\})=\{f(x)\,|\,f(x)\in Y\}=Y$$where the last equality follows from $f$ being surjective

Comment: @Lorago, thank you for your answer, but I think the problem is I don't see where this set comes from $\{x\in A | f(x)\in Y\}$. What's the intuition behind it? How do I come up with it?

Comment: @Lorago, and also why when we apply the function g to that set we get $\{f(x)|f(x)\in Y\}$? That's not clear for me as well. Thank you and sorry for the multiple questions, but I'm really trying to understand what's going on.

Comment: @MathStudent Applying $g$ to a set is the same as applying $f$ to every element in the set. The set we consider is simply the set of all points which map to $Y$ under $f$, meaning when we apply $g$ and apply $f$ to every element, all the points get mapped to $Y$